# How to call a list from a user input?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot specific lists from a selection of lists that I want to define by user input. However I don't know how to reference the list.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x = []
y = []
cd = []
cl = []

xInput = input("Please choose the x-value input: ")
yInput = input("Please choose the y-value input: ")

[...]

data_array = np.asarray(data)
aeroData = data_array.astype(np.float)

for i in range(aeroData.shape[0]):
    x.append(aeroData[i][0])
    y.append(aeroData[i][1])
    cd.append(aeroData[i][2])
    cl.append(aeroData[i][3])

plot(xInput, yInput)
plt.title("{} vs. {}".format(xInput, yInput))
plt.xlabel("{}".format(xInput))
plt.ylabel("{}".format(yInput))
plt.show
```

Comment: `plt.show`, it isn't called, you are just evaluating the function but not calling it.

Comment: Thank you! But I am referring to the line:  `plot(xInput, yInput)` Does that mean it doesn't work and I have to use conditions?

Comment: It's `plt.plot`, but that won't work either. *aeroData* is not defined. Half of your example is redundant code that isn't used for the plot. Which part belongs to the `numpy` tag?

Comment: what is exactly the value of `aereoData`?? could you show us the code when you define `aereoData`, and the code that is used for plotting??

Comment: I've edited my original question. @MichaelSzczesny : I know that the code is redundant but that's exactly what my question is aimed at. I want to know if it is possible to plot different lists from a "selection" of lists by specifying them via user input.

Comment: Now the question is: What is *data* and *liftData*?

Comment: _data_ is a list of lists. As explained below, the code runs flawlessly if I specify the list manually, like e. .g `plt.plot(y,cl)` however it doesn't work to define it that way as in my question.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. If you have additional informations please edit your question, don't post a comment to clarify.

Comment: @Michael Szczesny thank you for your effort, however the question is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Hamish Wormald 's suggestion. I got it to work now!

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x = []
y = []
cd = []
cl = []

xInput = input("Please choose the x-value input: ")
yInput = input("Please choose the y-value input: ")

[...]

data_array = np.asarray(data)
aeroData = data_array.astype(np.float)
    
aeroValues = [x, y, cd, cl]
aeroKeys = ["x", "y", "cd", "cl"]
aeroDict = dict(zip(aeroKeys, aeroValues))

if xInput in aeroKeys:
    if yInput in aeroKeys:
    # Plot data
    plt.plot(aeroDict[xInput], aeroDict[yInput], '-bo')
    plt.title("{} vs. {}".format(yInput, xInput))
    plt.xlabel("{}".format(xInput))
    plt.ylabel("{}".format(yInput))

    plt.savefig("{} vs. {}.png".format(yInput, xInput))

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The user input is a string.

If the user inputs a list of values:

```
xInput = [float(i) for i in input("Please choose the x-value input: ").split()]
```

If the list is already defined and the user is just referencing the variable by name, then:

```
xInput = globals().get(input("Please choose the x-value input: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `aeroData` somewhere if you haven't already somewhere else we cannot see.
Also, `plot` doesn't seem to be defined either. If you are trying to define it there you need:

```
def plot(xInput, yInput):
    plt.title("{} vs. {}".format(xInput, yInput))
    plt.xlabel("{}".format(xInput))
    plt.ylabel("{}".format(yInput))
    plt.show()
```

If it is part of pyplot you should need `plt.plot(xInput, yInput)`

Comment: Thanks but I cannot provide the full code unfortunately that's why I put [...] instead of that section. The code runs flawlessly if I specify the list manually, like e. .g `plt.plot(y,cl)` however it doesn't work to define it that way as in my question.

Comment: Oh, sorry I was looking more at the code itself rather than the error.  I think to do that we would need to know more context behind the code itself however I could maybe suggest using an array (or 2d array based on the fact you have a x and y value, never used these in python, they may not be in this language) . I would have an array/list of all the lists then when you call `plot` do `plt.plot(arrayName[xInput], arrayName[yInput])` where `arrayName` is the array/list of lists. Hope that helps

Comment: Please edit the supporting details in your comments into your answer to make it easier for viewers to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach is to use a for-loop to parse the input.

The code below will parse a comma separated string and trim all non digit characters, dots and dashes casting the result to float. The float number will be then appended to a 'numeric' array.

```py
x_input_str = input("Please choose the x-value input: ")
y_input_str = input("Please choose the y-value input: ")

xInput = []
for x in x_input_str.split(","):
    x = re.sub(pattern=r"([^0-9\.\-])", repl="", string=x.strip())
    xInput.append(float(x))

yInput = []
for y in y_input_str.split(","):
    y = re.sub(pattern=r"([^\d.-])", repl="", string=y.strip())
    yInput.append(float(y))
```